# Removing category and article tags from wordpress articles

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Sample article: https://www.thestyleprophet.in/travel-food/mango-juice-recipe/
I would like to not show the tag/category name which appears on the right hand side of the page after the title of the article. I could not find a plugin that can do this on the wordpress website. Please suggest.

The website has been generated using the following theme on wordpress. I do not have any other source code: https://www.jojo-themes.net/pluto-clean-personal-wordpress-masonry-blog-theme-v4-3-1/ I could not find any developer documentation on this as well.

Comment: We don't have access to your source code so we can't know how the page is generated. Also, when posting a question, you need to add all necessary information into the question itself, not as links off-site. When you've solved your issue (or rewritten your site), the question won't make any sense for future visitors.

Comment: The website has been generated using the following theme on wordpress. I do not have any other source code:
https://www.jojo-themes.net/pluto-clean-personal-wordpress-masonry-blog-theme-v4-3-1/
I could not find any developer documentation on this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `display` property for the category class to `none`.
Simply use the inspect element developer tool to confirm the particular class for the element you wish to hide.

```
.classname {
display:none;
}
```

In your case, adding this CSS will do the trick:

```
.post-categories {display:none;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On the WordPress dashboard, Go to Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS then copy and paste the snippet `.post-categories {display:none;}` in the box provided and publish the change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login as administrator
2. Settings > Permalinks > Common Settings
3. Choose "Post Name"
4. Set "." in each Optional Fields [Category base, Tag base]

Note: If other services used based on that WordPress site, be careful. It can crash other services. If website is alone, safe to change setting. Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you Lwin. The reason why I am having difficulty is because I need to remove the tags and categories from the article page and not from the URL. Please let me know if you have any suggestions